# Pandas datetime: Yearly comparison by day of week

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have datetime-indexed data in a `DataFrame`. For each date, I would like to compute the `pct_change` to the number from the previous year.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
idx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1000), index=idx)
```

*However*, I do **not** want to compute "previous year" by the same day and month. Instead, I want to compare each day in `2020` with the first day that has the same day-of-week in `2019`. What do I mean?

In the year 2020, January 1st was a Wednesday. In 2019, the first Wednesday was January 2nd. So difference by day-of-week would be `[value at 2020-01-01]/[value at 2019-01-02]`.

So for the comparison 2020-2019, I would simply need to know that there is a positive offset of +1, and hence go back [365-1] days for each comparison. What would be a generic solution for any two years?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61106105/python-how-to-find-the-nth-weekday-of-the-year#61106327

Answer (score 2):

This would do:

```
s = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.dayofweek]).cumcount()
shifted = df.groupby([s, df.index.dayofweek]).shift()

shifted.loc['2020-01-01']
# 0    1.0
# Name: 2020-01-01 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what exactly is happening here?